# Closing and opening files between conditions

Tags: python, file

I have a for cycle and inside of it a condition.
If the condition holds I'd like to create a file with certain name and write to it. If the condition does not hold I'd like to only write to file created in previous iterations.

The file name depends on x[0].

I haven't run it because it's clear that it won't run. How would you deal with the conditional closing and opening of files (always with new name)?

```
for x in dd:
  if x[1]: # close old file and start to write to new file
     ...
     f.close() # close the file (will not work in first iteration)
     fileName = "_".join(matchList) # create sensible file name
     f = open(fileName, "w")
     f.write(x[0])
  else:
    f.write(x[0])
```

Comment: Could you expand more on why it "won't run"? Your method seems ok to me.

Comment: @AndrewGelnar I probably need to create a file before for cycle, without associating it with filename and operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_file = something_that_creates_the_first_file()

for x in dd:
    if x[1]:  # Close old file and start to write to new file
        my_file.close()
        fileName = "_".join(matchList) # create sensible file name
        my_file = open(fileName, "w")

    my_file.write(x[0])

my_file.close()
```

Alternatively, you might be able to open and close the file every loop iteration, in which case you can do:

```
fileName = something_that_creates_the_first_file_name()

for x in dd:
    if x[1]:  # Close old file and start to write to new file
        fileName = "_".join(matchList) # create sensible file name

    with open(fileName, "a") as my_file:
        my_file.write(x[0])
```

This latter approach uses the built-in context management handlers for files to ensure if there are any errors, there is never a file left open.

Comment: My favorite would be to put the `for` loop inside a `try/finally` block that closes the file.

Comment: The first file name will be created from the dd[0][1], so than I will probably run the for cycle over dd[1:]. It looks ugly an weird according to code readability but seems the only one solution. So, I will use comments to make it readable.

Comment: @tdelaney, I can't think how to do that when the file object itself changes when you open the next one. Would be good to see the code if you can make it work.

Comment: @TomDalton I added an answer to demonstrate what I meant. But I'll keep my "like" on yours.

Comment: thanks, I created [continuation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144836/minimizing-open-close-scenario) of the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is @tomdalton's answer with a slight update to add a try/finally block. His should remain the accepted answer, I'm just adding an error management tweak. `with` clauses are great but only work when the resource should be managed in the clause. Otherwise, you need to fall back to a basic `finally` block.

```
my_file = something_that_creates_the_first_file()
try:
    for x in dd:
        if x[1]:  # Close old file and start to write to new file
            my_file.close()
            fileName = "_".join(matchList) # create sensible file name
            my_file = open(fileName, "w")

        my_file.write(x[0])
finally:
    my_file.close()
```

Comment: thanks, I created [continuation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144836/minimizing-open-close-scenario) of the question.

Comment: @xralf - this answer answers that question. Mostly this is just a case of opening new files and putting them in the `my_file` variable for future writes. The `finally` is used to catch the case where an exception is raised and it will do the final file close.